# Config transformation special situation

Tags: web-config, transformation, web.config-transform

I have the following config file

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Demo" value="true"/>
      <setting name="Demo2" value="true"/>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And I want it transformed into this

```
<configuration xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone OR ContentDelivery OR ContentManagement">
   <settings>
        <setting name="Demo" value="false"/>
        <setting name="Demo2" value="true"/>
   </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to use this https://fatantelopetester.apphb.com/ and obtained the following transformation config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(xmlns:role,xmlns:set)" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone OR ContentDelivery OR ContentManagement" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(role:require)">
    <settings>
      <setting name="Demo" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" value="false" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

But apparently this transformation is not good enough and not working. 
Any ideas how to make it work, in conditions when under

```
<sitecore>
```

I have lots of other setting? (Here I've added just a sample)

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly doesn't work for you? The xdt transformation on https://fatantelopetester.apphb.com/ or xdt transformation in your Visual Studio?

Comment: @A.Dylevich the transformation in Visual Studio its not working.

Comment: The first thing I would check is the <TransformOnBuild> presence in csproj xml file. Here's an example:


    <Content Include="App_Config\Include\Z\Demo.config">
      <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Content>
    <None Include="App_Config\Demo.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Demo.config</DependentUpon>
      <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
    </None>

Comment: The next thing worth mentioning is install the SlowCheetah nuget package that helps you to do the transformations

Comment: @A.Dylevich I have already tried that, including having SlowCheetah. I get this error in fact, in Visual Studio. 
Error  Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.   All other kind of transformations do work just fine. I think is the line `<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(xmlns:role,xmlns:set)" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> ` is not ok.

Comment: Do you really need this xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(xmlns:role,xmlns:set)"  ? I'му got the same error when I insert it into my transformations, without this attribute transformation works fine

Comment: Well, yes. I think its needed, as the end result that I want its this `<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(xmlns:role,xmlns:set)" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">`. But it looks that its impossible to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar issue myself and found a solution that worked for me. I'm not using SlowCheetah but I am using a tool that uses XDT under the hood.

The XDT would fail around `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(role:require)"` because the namespace wasn't found. However, using `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"` didn't seem to have the same problem and was able to set the attribute just fine.